# Powershell: Directly write hex values?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a "secret" key. My theory (was/is) to write out non-printable hex codes, (such as `0x02, 0x09, 0x1E` ...) of which there are 12 such codes. These are then saved out to a 'fake' file, such as ".sss" (on Windows) which should be unreadable - accept to savy programmers. And if the file is opened, it will display "      "

I have tried numerous combinations, such as using double and single quotes, using "\x02", "O:x02" or "Ox02" but it always outputs as the exact string. I tried "Format-Hex" ... but that simply outputs a table showing the string, and respective hex codes for "0","x","0" and "2"

Using my text editor - which has a hex editor - I'm able to enter 02 09 1D 1E etc which, when switched back to text mode shows "      "

Is this even possible with Powershell? Below is my test script

```
$myPath = Split-Path $PSScriptRoot
$out_file="$myPath\.sss"
$file="0:x020:x090:x1D0:x1E0:x1F\x1c\x81\x8F\x8D\x8F\x9\x9d\xA0"
$file>"$myPath\.sss";
write-host("file to $myPath\.sss")
```

(The latter line is just to verify the location of the save) My **THEORY** is I could enter something like `02 1E 1C 81 8D A0`, store it in the fake file, and then load that into another part of the program to check it matches a similar code embedded at start of a javascript/text file.

*Hope this meets with approval as my last post was deleted as: "This is not a script writing service"*

This is to make each computer running my other program 'unique' so that scripts are not used on other PC's. Originally, I used code that was reading the "DigitalProductId" from registry, but A) that now returns a null entry from registry, or B) displays as "BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBB"

---

I would like to thank the person who pointed me in the direction of `[char]0x09` etc. Here is the resultant code that might help others.

```
$myPath = Split-Path $PSScriptRoot

## This part write out all the invisible codes to a file.
$file=[char]0x02+[char]0x09+[char]0x1D+[char]0x1E+[char]0x1F+[char]0x1C+[char]0x81+[char]0X8F+[char]0x8D+[char]0x8F+[char]0x90+[char]0x9d+[char]0xA0
$file|Out-File -NoNewLine "$myPath\.sss";

## The file is saved in the format "FE FF 02 00 09 00 1D 00 ..."
## This part reads the file in again as bytes
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content $myPath\.sss -Encoding Byte
$hexString = ($bytes|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''
$tot=$bytes.Count
$tot=($tot*2)-4; 
# Since we start 4 bytes in, we must end 4 bytes early to avoid reading past end of file.
# We double $tot as there are two numbers per array cell

## It skips the BOM at the start (FEFF), and then skips over the "00" entries by moving 4 bytes along, and then taking next two bytes as substring
for ($i=4; $i -le $tot; $i=$i+4 ) {
$output+=$hexString.Substring($i,2)
}

write-host($output);
## In my case, I would use any 3x [char]0x?? to create a unique 6 digit number (1,716 combinations) or 4x (17,160 combinations)

## If users find this file, they will see ".ssa", and Windows will not know how to display the file
## For the few that do, they will see "      " entry
## If people copy the other app to another PC WITHOUT this secret file, it will refuse to run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[char]0xCode` syntax, E.G.

```
[char]0x02
[char]0x09
[char]0x1D
```

Comment: Use like this: `"$([char]0x02)"` where in place of 02 place the hex code.

Comment: I got it to work as per your original method. The problem was I was using a dot to join codes rather than "+" Now works ALMOST correctly, just creates it as "02 00 09 00 1D 00", which I believe is "big Endian" coding. So got to look into encoding to get it back to single digits ... although this is a minor thing. If the worst happens, I can simply skip alternate digits when checking. Many thanks for your help. Alas, not able to upvote

Comment: Welcome @ChrisBrown, to upvote click the ^ looking button. Glad to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, to upvote you have to register. Alas, some of my early questions mean the email address is on a "blacklist", and if I complete the signup, I won't be able to post at all !